# Perforce: How Not To Forget Reconcile Offline Work?

Tags: perforce

I sometimes forget to commit offline work in perforce as you cannot see them in the pending changelist.

> Does anyone know how to force user to put offline work into pending
>   list or can it be done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to force reconcile to be run before submit I would create a custom submit dialog in P4V. The API is detailed here:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4jsapi/p4jsapi.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try to get yourself in the habit of reconciling even when you know exactly which files you worked on and they're already in a changelist.

Personally, I'm currently working with an IDE that claims to integrate with Perforce but in fact does not actually do anything, so I have to reconcile before *any* changes are picked up. I remember to scan for changes because it's indispensable.